# Enable equal sign in cookies in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

In undertow web-server there is an option to enable equal sign in cookie by setting ALLOW_EQUALS_IN_COOKIE_VALUE to true. When value is false (which is the default) the server remove the equal sign from cookie value.

How can i configure undertow in Quarkus with this option